# Where em campo integer[] Postgresql

Tags: php, postgresql

Estou criando um select onde preciso verificar em uma das colunas que é do tipo integer[] se possui um dos valores passados na condição.

por exemplo:

```
idTarefa | Setores
1        | {1,3,4}
2        | {2}
```

Sabendo que a coluna Setores é integer[] (array), como posso fazer um select solicitando que verifique se nesta coluna exista o valor de outro array.

Já tentei fazer da seguinte forma:

```
select * from tarefas WHERE IN(ARRAY[2,4])
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Array

Na [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html) temos :

> Para procurar um valor em um array, cada valor necessita ser verificado. Isto pode ser feito manualmente, se você sabe o tamnho do array.

#### Exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE pay_by_quarter[1] = 10000 OR
                            pay_by_quarter[2] = 10000 OR
                            pay_by_quarter[3] = 10000 OR
                            pay_by_quarter[4] = 10000;
```

> Contudo, isto sera tedioso caso tenha um array muito grande, e não ajuda caso o tamanho do array seja desconhecido. Uma alternativa é usar o método `ANY`.

#### Exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE 10000 = ANY (pay_by_quarter);
```

> Além disso, você pode encontrar linhas onde a matriz tem todos os valores iguais a 10000.

#### Exemplo

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp WHERE 10000 = ALL (pay_by_quarter);
```

### JSON

A partir da versão 9.5 do PostgreSQL esta disponível pesquisa por valor do json.

[Documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html)

Você poderia fazer algo assim :

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE column_name::jsonb ? array['b', 'c'];
```

Comment: Realmente @Guilherme desta forma `SELECT * FROM tb_tarefas WHERE 2 = ANY (Setores);` ele me retorna as tarefas, porém se eu tenho mais do que um número para verificar como procedo? Pois eu tenho que passar um array de Setores para verificar se naquela tarefa existe algum destes setores.

Comment: Guilherme obrigado pela sua ajuda, funcionou para mim os exemplos que me passou, somente não consegui fazer o ultimo. Agora só vou resolver como faço de um forma fácil para verificar se os valores dentro de um array existe dentro de outro. Mais uma vez Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Eu conheço duas formas de fazer:

**1º Forma:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tarefas 
WHERE   Setores = ANY(ARRAY[2, 4]);
```

**2º Forma:**

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tarefas 
WHERE   Setores IN (2, 4);
```

Comment: Usando qualquer uma das opções ele me retorna este erro:
**HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.**

O primeiro para no sinal de "=" (igual) antes do _ANY_ e o seguindo para no _IN_

Comment: Você esta passando alguma variável em php ou esta colocando o número direto ?

Comment: Neste momento, só estou testando diretamente no pgAdmin, passando o select.

Fazendo desta forma:
`SELECT * FROM tb_tarefas WHERE cod_subsetores @> ARRAY[2,4];` ele até me retorna algo, porém somente a tarefa que tem no array o número 2 e o número 4, a outra tarefa que tem somente o número 2 ele não me retorna.

Comment: Não consigo encontrar nada na documentação sobre o operador mencionado *@>* http://pgdocptbr.sourceforge.net/pg80/functions-comparison.html

Comment: Sobre este operador você pode encontrar aqui esta informação: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html